# Redirect stdout from unix to hadoop without writing file in Unix

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, hadoop

I have a process that would download a file, then unzip it a file and then send it to HDFS.
We saw a way to optimize it as follows using the command **--to-stdout** and it worked wonders for us:

```
gunzip --to-stdout "${FULLNAME}" | hdfs dfs -put - "${path_folder}/${PROCESS}"
```

The question I have is regarding the stdout:

Is it possible to do something similar with a sql query? That is, throw the result you get and send it to the HDFS with a filename?

We have something like this that generates a file and then send it to the hdfs.

```
sqlplus -S user/password@dbname << EOF > file_name.txt
    set feedback off trimspool on
    select * from table_name;
    exit;
EOF

hdfs dfs -put file_name.txt ${path_folder}
```

What I would like to know is if there is a way to take the output from the output without redirecting it to a file but directly, like the example I put of the decompression, send it to the HDFS?

Comment: don't forget to double-quote `$path_folder`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like your original example, you can use the pipe (`|`) to redirect your sqlplus command too. Just put the pipe in the same line as the first `EOF`:

```bash
sqlplus -S user/password@dbname << EOF | hdfs dfs -put - ${path_folder}/file_name.txt
    set feedback off trimspool on
    select * from table_name;
    exit;
EOF
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer Omajid. I just tried and the only thing I see is that it generates the file but without name. Is there any way to "name" that stdout to be able to put it in the hdfs?

Comment: You can use `hdfs dfs -put - ${path_folder}/file_name.txt` and specify the target file name

Answer (score 1):

Just redirect as in your example

```
sqlplus -S user/password@dbname <<EOF | hdfs dfs -put - ${path_folder}
    set feedback off trimspool on
    select * from table_name;
    exit;
EOF
```

If it can be redirected to a file then it can be redirected to a pipe.

Comment: Greetings Diego. I already tried, it works but it generates a file with no name. Do you know if this standard output can be given a name to be able to put it in the hdfs?